# Liquibase - Diff between changelog and database

Tags: liquibase

Before we implement / apply new changes to the database, we would like to see the list of pending changes that will be applied. So essentially it is a diff between the latest changelog (yet to be applied to the DB) and the DB. I tried looking around for getting this working - but seems like Liquibase is unable to do this. Does this have a workaround?

This is mainly to be sure of what changes will get applied in the current release if update the DB using liquibase. We are using liquibase v3.8.9.

Midhun

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a list of pending SQL to be applied to the target database, updateSQL is what you should look for:
https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/updatesql.html

It does exactly this:
"a diff between the latest changelog (yet to be applied to the DB) and the DB.
"

The output (along with other debug info) will be the SQL Liquibase *would* run if you called just plain *update*